# How to predict one value based on a series input of 2D shape correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, prediction

I am using an **encoder-decoder** architecture, with 3 layers each in the encoder and decoder and 128 neurons in each hidden layer. The **inputs are in a 2D form**: the first column has the days and the second column has the time series dependent on the days (shape:(5780, 100, 2)). The **output is a single value** among the values of the first column, that represents a particular day when the breaking point occurs (shape:(5780, 1, 1)). The breaking point is one of the time dependent values i.e. the second column.

A better picture of the input is:

```
array([[  0.        ,   1.        ],
       [  2.        ,   1.14469799],
       [  4.        ,   1.35245666],
       ...,
       [ 96.        ,   1.80030942],
       [ 98.        ,   1.79964733],
       [100.        ,   1.9898739]])
```

Where the days are in the first column and the corresponding points measured are in the second column.

The output is just a single value, which represents the day at which the breaking point occurs:

```
array([[1108.]])
```

The problem is that after training, the output on all different test data is almost exactly the same, i.e. it gives the same day for breaking points of all different materials (with just negligible changes in the decimal places). I have experimented with high and low learning rates (ranging 1e-2 to 1e-5), the number of training epochs (300 to 3000). I have also varied the number of layers and the neurons per layer.

What I haven't done is batch normalization or any kind of normalization, but I had done some operations with the same data having the same gradients, and it worked perfectly fine.

The architecture that I'm using here is as follows:

```
nodes = 128
drp = 0.01

# Defining input layers and shapes
input_train = Input(shape = (complete_inputs.shape[1], complete_inputs.shape[2]))
output_train = Input(shape= (kp_targets.shape[1], kp_targets.shape[2]))

# Masking layer
masking_layer = Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape = input_train.shape)(input_train)

# Encoder layer. For simple S2S model, we only need the last state_h and the last state_c.
enc_first_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=drp, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))(masking_layer)
enc_first_layer, enc_fwd_h1, enc_fwd_c1, enc_back_h1, enc_back_c1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=drp, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))(enc_first_layer)
enc_stack_h, enc_fwd_h2, enc_fwd_c2, enc_back_h2, enc_back_c2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=drp, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))(enc_first_layer)

enc_last_h1 = concatenate([enc_fwd_h1, enc_back_h1])
enc_last_h2 = concatenate([enc_fwd_h2, enc_back_h2])
enc_last_c1 = concatenate([enc_fwd_c1, enc_back_c1])
enc_last_c2 = concatenate([enc_fwd_c2, enc_back_c2])


# RepeatVector layer (using only the last hidden state of encoder)
rv = RepeatVector(output_train.shape[1])(enc_last_h2)

# Stacked decoder layer for alignment score calculation (using the last hidden state of encoder)
dec_stack_h = Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=drp, return_state=False, return_sequences=True))(rv, initial_state=[enc_fwd_h1, enc_fwd_c1, enc_back_h1, enc_back_c1])
dec_stack_h = Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=drp, return_state=False, return_sequences=True))(dec_stack_h)
dec_stack_h = Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=drp, return_state=False, return_sequences=True))(dec_stack_h, initial_state=[enc_fwd_h2, enc_fwd_c2, enc_back_h2, enc_back_c2])


# Attention layer (uses STACKED encoder output and dots it with stacked decoder output)
attention_ = dot([dec_stack_h, enc_stack_h], axes=[2,2])
attention_ = Activation('softmax')(attention_)

# Calculating the context vector
context = dot([attention_, enc_stack_h], axes=[2,1])

# Concat the context vector and stacked hidden states of decoder, and use it as input to the last dense layer
dec_combined_context = concatenate([context, dec_stack_h])


# Output Timedistributed dense layers
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(nodes/2, activation='relu'))(dec_combined_context)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_train.shape[2], activation='linear'))(dec_combined_context)

# Compile model
model_attn = Model(inputs=input_train, outputs=out)
opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.004)
model_attn.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=masked_mae)
```

What could be going wrong here?

Just to have a broader view on the problem, I also had the following question in mind: Is this model an overkill? Is there another machine/deep learning model that is more suited to predicting this kind of an output with the data that I have?

I have been at this problem for a week with no improvements, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1: Tried Normalization using StandardScaler and a simpler architecture. No improvements so far. Following is the structure with the commented-out sections implemented in all possible combinations..**

```
nodes = 130 # Tried with 10/30/40/80

model_attn = Sequential()
#model_attn.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape = (complete_inputs.shape[1], complete_inputs.shape[2])))

#model_attn.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True)))
#model_attn.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True)))
model_attn.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(nodes, dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False)))

model_attn.add(Dense(1))
model_attn.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss = 'MAE')
```

No drop in losses over time:

```
model_attn.fit(complete_inputs, kp_targets, batch_size=350, epochs=300, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[callback])

Epoch 1/300
11/11 [==============================] - 18s 2s/step - loss: 0.7930 - val_loss: 0.3486
Epoch 2/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7544 - val_loss: 0.5152
Epoch 3/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7406 - val_loss: 0.4794
Epoch 4/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7385 - val_loss: 0.5361
Epoch 5/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7367 - val_loss: 0.4821
Epoch 6/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7350 - val_loss: 0.5518
Epoch 7/300
11/11 [==============================] - 18s 2s/step - loss: 0.7344 - val_loss: 0.5151
Epoch 8/300
11/11 [==============================] - 17s 2s/step - loss: 0.7339 - val_loss: 0.5646
Epoch 9/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7380 - val_loss: 0.5277
Epoch 10/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7382 - val_loss: 0.4879
Epoch 11/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7367 - val_loss: 0.5367
Epoch 12/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7382 - val_loss: 0.4910
Epoch 13/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7354 - val_loss: 0.5244
Epoch 14/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7386 - val_loss: 0.5043
Epoch 15/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7329 - val_loss: 0.5421
Epoch 16/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7376 - val_loss: 0.5023
Epoch 17/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7346 - val_loss: 0.4539
.....
.....

Epoch 27/300
11/11 [==============================] - 15s 1s/step - loss: 0.7388 - val_loss: 0.5649
Epoch 28/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7329 - val_loss: 0.6575
Epoch 29/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7400 - val_loss: 0.5123
Epoch 30/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7336 - val_loss: 0.4965
Epoch 31/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7328 - val_loss: 0.5069
Epoch 32/300
11/11 [==============================] - 17s 2s/step - loss: 0.7320 - val_loss: 0.5274
Epoch 33/300
11/11 [==============================] - 17s 2s/step - loss: 0.7302 - val_loss: 0.5968
Epoch 34/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7354 - val_loss: 0.6161
....
....
....
Epoch 184/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7088 - val_loss: 0.8242
Epoch 185/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7034 - val_loss: 0.7799
Epoch 186/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7098 - val_loss: 0.8179
Epoch 187/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7066 - val_loss: 0.7854
Epoch 188/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7142 - val_loss: 0.8340
Epoch 189/300
11/11 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.7123 - val_loss: 0.7197
```

With no particular order of increase or decrease in both the losses. I have also stopped training at the epochs with the minimum losses, but with no improvements.

**UPDATE 1:** There was a mistake in the application of the StandardScalar. After fixing it, it did seem to output different predictions for the test dataset!

**UPDATE 2:** For these types of predictions, CNNs are also a great choice. However, comparison between the two architectures still need to be done. Will update my findings here!

**UPDATE 3:** For these types of predictions, CNNs are a much better choice than LSTMs as the data pertains to more of a classification problem. Although with more layers of LSTMs and tuning of the hyperparameters can work, my experiments showed that for similar results, CNNs perform AT LEAST 12 times faster than LSTMs, and also possibly with lower memory usage.

Comment: Output is too big. The input is only 1-2 which is insignificant compare to >1000. Also normally I only see output value normalized to be rather small (less than 10).

Comment: And I suppose you're using `float32`, the biggest value you can get out of that is only 255.

Comment: This task also more like classification problem. Predicting more than 1000 classes from 5000 images is too difficult. Maybe it'll be better if you simply use `categorical_crossentropy` over 100 classes and each class represent 10 days?

Comment: If you want to stick with regression then I'd first try normalize the output to be less than 10.

Comment: There must be a mistake in understanding. The inputs are two series, while the output is a single valued integer, not the number of classes. But sure, I could try normalization.

Comment: If the outputs are all in a specified range (say 500-1000) I'd first make a classifier to predict which day. This is to verify if the data is actually possible to train and CCE is much easier to converge compare to MAE.

Comment: Your outputs are all integers, which means you don't have data of a fraction of a day. This is much like review score prediction where you need to predict how many stars you can get from a text.

Comment: What did you exactly mean by 'first make a classifier to predict which day'? Should I try a classifier instead of a regressor for the complete problem or only partially? I have not used a classifier before, so a little more specificity could help :)

Comment: For example, if my data has outputs consist of days evenly distributed between 1-1000 and the model isn't converging. I'll try make it a classifier of 10 classes of 0-100, 101-200 etc. and measure accuracy. This will reduce what a model need to predict from literally infinite to only 10. And the output values are capped to 0-1 which is much easier to work with.

Comment: If this works but normal regression doesn't work then you need more data or the the output is too big.

Comment: But you'll probably need regression anyway as classification only works with predetermined classes so if you can make regression work with just normalize the output the just use that.

Comment: I'll try the suggestions and post the results or further queries here. Thank you for showing a way, Natthaphon

Comment: Note that there's no notification for editing the post. Only new comment.

Comment: Also I just notice. The model seems to be..... too complicated. Too many `LSTM`/`Dense` usually result in gradient vanish and `TimeDistributed` at the output looks... out of place. May be this will work with just an `LSTM` and a plain `Dense`?

Comment: I tried some methods suggested so far. Have mentioned them in the edits.

Comment: There's still the fact that I prefer classification for this task. You know `Dense` layer is just sum of the product of input and weight right? Make that value correct is much more difficult than make the correct node higher than others.

Comment: Also maybe `Conv1D` also work? You can stack a lot of convolution layer without gradient vanish

Comment: I have to agree that it is easier to treat this as a classification problem and have a few thousand possible outputs... It is generally easier for neural networks to handle small numbers than big ones.

Comment: I am implementing the CNN architecture. What should be the suggested number of classes? Should it be the number of total target variables? (There are a total of 40 unique target variables i.e. breaking point values)

Comment: @HarryS, is there a reason why you choose Encoder Decoder architecture with LSTM? I've seen that kind of architecture being use for anomalies detection in signal reconstruction. But, as mention above by Natthaphon, your model does seems very complicated as a first start. If using CNN with sevral layersi'll advice using

Comment: @HarryS, [sorry..]  i'll advice trying with and without BatchNormalisation. 
Finally, even though Adam is a very popular optimizer it can be unstable sometimes (val_losses going up and down), In my case switching to SGD resulted in slower and smoother learning curve.

Comment: If your network is outputting the same value for every input, then I would suggest you to take some random input, make your model predict the answer to that random input, if that is the same as all the other outputs, then it would mean that your model is converting every input to some garbage at some point. Then you could check the output of the network and the loss by removing layer by layer, this way you can see at which point all the inputs are being converted to a **garbage**.

Comment: Also, the same thing happened to me, but using BatchNormalization at some right points, fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, normalization indeed helped with the same-value-output issue!

Comment: Harry, it is good that you fixed the issue, I would suggest you to now understand why did normalization fixed it. That way, you will really understand about normalization in deep. And, if you already have figured out that how did Normalization helped. Then, Congratulations! You now understand Normalization a lot better now!